# how to run histoire-svelte plugin in vscode?

Tags: svelte

I do not know how to use this plugin inside vscode:

https://github.com/histoire-dev/histoire/tree/main/packages/histoire-plugin-svelte

could you help me to use it in a new project ?
screen:
https://elk.zone/mastodon.world/@histoire@webtoo.ls/109843179369486673

tks

i ve tried pnpm build, and it does not appear in the cmd palette

i have nothing more to write for detail, why I have to do this ?